# mocha false negative result

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I'm testing a function that generates credentials based on the username and password that are passed in:

```
generateCredentials(username, password) {
  return {
    username: username,
    password: password
  };
}
```

Here is my test:

```
describe('#generateCredentials(username, password)', function() {
    it('creates a JSON object with the passed in arguments', function() {

      var creds = generateCredentials('user', 'pass');

      var expectedCreds =  { username: 'user', password: 'pass' };

      expect(creds).to.equal(expectedCreds);
    });
  });
```

I get an error:

```
AssertionError: expected { username: 'user', password: 'pass' } to equal { username: 'user', password: 'pass' }
```

I don't see any difference in what is expected and what is actually being returned. I `console.log` `creds & expectedCreds` and they are identical. Why is mocha throwing an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect(...).to.equal` tests if objects strictly equal (like with `===` operator). In javascript objects with the same properties and values are not equal:

```
({ prop: 'value' }) === ({ prop: 'value' }); // false
```

You can use `expect(...).to.eql` to find if object deeply equals:

```
expect(creds).to.eql(expectedCreds);
```

Notice: I suppose you use chai assertion library.